# Detect Android 14's dynamic colors is in monochrome/grayscale mode

Tags: android, kotlin, android-14

Android 14 (UpsideDownCake) has a monochrome/grayscale dynamic colors theme as can be seen in [1](https://9to5google.com/2023/03/08/monochrome-theme-custom-clocks-android-14-dp2/), how can I detect the mode to make further tweaks for the mode, e.g. making UI elements that don't use R.color.system_* such as UI images grayscale, in this mode?

[image: A screenshot of monochrome mode]

(a screenshot of Android 14's preview images by me)

Answer (score 0):

This answer will hopefully be updated with Android 14's final release but apparently per [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/12hmg5d/android_14_is_adding_support_for_generating/) there will be `AccessibilityManager.getUiContrast()` which I couldn't find right now but a naïve solution that might be helpful also on older version of Android (that possibly can get a custom version of monochrome mode using third party apps) perhaps could be to use something like this which I'm putting here for review,

```
// You probably shouldn't use the following code,
val Context.isDynamicGrayscale: Boolean
    get() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.S) return false
        val hsv = FloatArray(3)
        return listOf(
            android.R.color.system_accent1_500,
            android.R.color.system_accent2_500,
            android.R.color.system_accent3_500,
        ).all { Color.colorToHSV(getColor(it), hsv); hsv[1] < .25 }
    }
```

Update: Apparently Android 13 extension 5 also can have the monotone mode so above code isn't that pointless.

Update 2:
`context.getSystemService<UiModeManager>()?.contrast` returns 0 regardless of being monochrome or not in an Android emulator so this isn't they way to detect a monochrome and probably current answer isn't that bad.

Comment: I was looking into this, and it appears that getUiContrast (along with some other UIContrast-related methods) was added in DP1 but removed in Beta 1. Not sure whether it will be coming back. 

https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/u-beta1-incr/changes/android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager#android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager.getUiContrast_removed()

Comment: @Mark those UIContrast-related methods were moved to `android.app.UiModeManager`